# Normal approxiamation to Binomial distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

A company has $200$ employees. Assume that each employee invites $2$ guests, independently, to attend a promotion seminar with a probability of $0.8$. How many seats should be provided if the company desires to be $99\%$ confident of seating everyone? (Using Normal approximation to binomial distribution)

I am doing it with:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathrm{E}(x) =& (400)(0.8) &= 320 \\
\mathrm{Var}(x) =& (400)(0.8)(0.2) &= 64
\end{array}
$$

How should I determine the number of seats then?

Comment: It has been over two years. Would you consider deleting this question post or accept the answer to wrap it up? I assume you have already got your answer here or elsewhere and moved on.

Comment: Hello? Are you there. Again, please accept the answer and "conclude" this post.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the normal approximation is

$P(X \leq x)=\Phi\left( \frac{x+0.5-\mu}{\sigma} \right)$

$=\Phi\left( \frac{x+0.5-320}{\sqrt{64}} \right)=0.99$

$\Phi(\cdot )$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution. $+0.5$ in the numerator is the continuity correction factor.

Taking the inverse function to solve for x.

$\frac{x+0.5-320}{\sqrt{64}}=\Phi ^{-1}\left( 0.99\right)$

$\sqrt{64}=8$ and to get the value of $\Phi ^{-1}\left( 0.99\right)$ you look at a [table](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~soshniko/135a/materials/standardnormaltable.pdf) of the standard normal distribution. You´ll see that the corresponding value is $2.33$. The equation becomes

$\frac{x+0.5-320}{8}=2.33$

Solve for x. The result should be rounded up to a whole number.